# FileNotFoundError while trying to load dataset from drive

Tags: python, path, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, file-not-found

I have been trying to load the NWPU VHR-10 dataset in Google collab from a directory in Google drive using 'on.listdir()' function .

However, I encountered a 'FileNotFoundError' when trying to access the directory where the positive image set located.

I am getting the following error message:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/deeplearning_dataset/NWPU VHR-10 dataset/positive image set'`

I have confirmed that the dataset is stored in my Google drive, and that I have the correct permissions to access it.

I have also tried modifying the directory paths to ensure that they match the directory names in my Google drive.

Here is the code i am using :

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')`
pos_img_dir ="/content/drive/My Drive/deeplearning_dataset/NWPU VHR-10 dataset/positive image set"
pos_img_files = [f for f in os.listdir(pos_img_dir) if f.endswith('.jpg')]
pos_img_files = np.array(pos_img_files)
```

I have used "os.path.join()" to join the base path and the filename, but still get the same error:

```
pos_img_dir ="/content/drive/My Drive/deeplearning_dataset/NWPU VHR-10 dataset/positive image set"

pos_img_files = [os.path.join(pos_img_dir, f) for f in os.listdir(pos_img_dir) if f.endswith('.jpg')]

pos_img_files = np.array(pos_img_files)
```

Comment: os.listdir() returns only *filenames*, you have to add the base path to the filename *if* your current working directory is different than the base path